# How many ContentProvider?

Tags: android, database, android-contentprovider

In my application I access drectly to database through a SQLiteOpenHelper object.

Now I want to use ContentProviders. In the database I have 14 tables and 6 views. What is the best practice between the following?

1. One Content Provider to access all tables and views
2. One Content Provider for each tables and views (total 20 Content Providers)
3. One Content Provider for each group of tables and views (totale 5/6 Content Providers)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One content provider to access all the tables and views in a database. Content Provider is a abstraction for application to share data with other applications. One Content Provider for a database should be the approach.

Comment: Ok Thanks.My SQLiteOpenHelper object has a lot of method, how can I replicate them in Content Provider? For example, I have fetch methods for every table, I have to copy this methods in Content Provider query method? And how I can call the different code in this same method?